# How to pass textbox value to this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this textbox

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" required="required" id="bar" name="bar" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode">
```

and this button

```
<button type="button" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Generate Barcode</button>
```

I want to get that texbox value and pass it tho this script to generate a barcode

```
    <center><img id="barcode2"/>

    <script>
        JsBarcode("#barcode2", "9780199532179", {
          format:"EAN13",
          displayValue:true,
          fontSize:24
        });
    </script>
    </center>
```

The "9780199532179" is supposed to be the textbox value. I've tried to create a function with the script and everything but i can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer this page for your solution http://lindell.me/JsBarcode/
generally store the value by it's tag name into a js variable
i.e., var i=document.getElementById("bar").value;
    
        JsBarcode("#barcode2",i, {format:"EAN13",displayValue:true,        fontSize:24 });

Comment: Found It! Thanks a lot man! I downloaded the scripts from github with no refer links!

Comment: That's great my fellow

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you can read the value of the element using `$("#bar").val()`. This value can be then passed into your function.

It would look something like this:

```
var inputVal = $("#bar").val();
JsBarcode("#barcode2", inputVal, {
  format:"EAN13",
  displayValue:true,
  fontSize:24
});
```

Comment: Also remember to invoke this script when needed.. like on `click` of that button created

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("bar").value`

I hope this is you looking for. If you dont know about  what i mentioned please google getElementById  and go to W3school tutorial